# Using Azure Data Factory, how to extract data from arrays in documents of DocumentDB to SQL Database

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory

I need to extract arrays from documents in a DocumentDB and copy to SQL Database using Azure Data Factory..

I need to implement the same functionality of using jsonNodeReference and jsonPathDefinition in "**Sample 2: cross apply multiple objects with the same pattern from array**" of this article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-supported-file-and-compression-formats#json-format

Answer (score 0):

According to your mentioned [File and compression formats supported by Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-supported-file-and-compression-formats#json-format), it seems that it is not supported to extract data from documentdb to SQL database with Azure Data Factory Copy Activity currently. We  could give our [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db) to Azure document Team.

> This topic applies to the following connectors: **Amazon S3**, **Azure Blob**, **Azure Data Lake Store**, **File System**, **FTP**, **HDFS**, **HTTP**, and **SFTP**.

But we also could use [custom activities in an Azure Data Factory pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-use-custom-activities) or Azure [WebJob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-create-web-jobs)/Function with customized logic to do that.

Some related documents:

[How to to Query Azure Cosmos DB resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/documentdb-get-started#Query)

[How to operate Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-design-first-database-csharp#cs_1_connect)